# ZendFramework - Finding out what queries are being run - Easier way

Tags: debugging, zend-framework, profiling

Was wondering if there is an easier way to see the queries are being being run by my models?

I know the alternate options are xDebug and Firebug but was wondering an easier method.

Anyone?

Thanks

Comment: one option i know is save them in a log file

Comment: If it's a local dev server it might be appropriate to just tail the database server's log. You can enable logging of all queries in my.cnf for MySQL.

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.profiler.html Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009639/zend-db-framework-examine-query-for-an-update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ZF debug bar adds an overlay to your page and provides info on file usage, memory usage and which database calls were made when the page was loaded:

http://jokke.dk/software/zfdebug

Answer (score 6):

using Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug is very easy look at :

http://www.peacocksuit.com/blog/2008/09/02/zend-framework-logging-database-queries-to-firebug/

Comment: +1 - Very easy to set up this method purely via config / application resources (no code required). I've had issues with debug toolbar messing up client-side too much, plus it doesn't work with non-HTML responses.

Answer (score 0):

for all of us using github

```
git clone git://github.com/jokkedk/ZFDebug.git
```