# how to dump generated query

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

i have an update query that i am getting error

```
Message: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match  number of tokens
```

i would like to have my query display so that i could debug it. any ideas how to do this

EDIT::
on my page.php model i have and Page model extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract

```
public static function updatePage($data, $id)
{       
    $row = new self();
    $row->update($data, "page_id = ?".$id);
}
```

Comment: $row->update($data, "page_id =".$id); solved my problem but still question remains open so what it would be easier to debug our db application

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use "Zend_Db_Select":

```
<?php

Zend_Debug::dump($select->__toString()); // nice formatted debug
echo $select; // altough ok !
```

Comment: @ArneRie can't i dump out my update query that is built be the above code. Please check edits

Comment: @ArneRie it does not show update query (db profiler shows only successful query)

Comment: ok check the last response to this topic, not elegant but working :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009639/zend-db-framework-examine-query-for-an-update